# how can i access function in private class?

Tags: c++

```
template<typename DataType>
class AVLTree
{
    public:

    private:
        class AVLNode
        {
        public:
            DataType data;
            int balanceFactor;
            AVLNode *left;
            AVLNode *right;
            AVLNode():balanceFactor(0),left(NULL),right(NULL){}
            AVLNode(DataType item):balanceFactor(0), data(item),left(NULL), right(NULL){}
        };
        typedef AVLNode* AVLNodePointer;
        AVLNodePointer root;
        int height(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp);
        int different(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer temp);
        AVLNodePointer ll_rotation(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer parent);

};

template<typename DataType>
AVLNodePointer AVLTree<DataType>:: ll_rotation(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer parent)
{
}
```

but this declaration gives a compiler error. How can I declare this function outside of the class? Just edit some typing error but still have error

Comment: What is the compiler error exactly?

Comment: It say AVLNodePointer does not name a type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template<typename DataType>
typename AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer AVLTree<DataType>::ll_rotation(AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer parent)
{
}
```

The `AVLNodePointer` type is only defined in the `AVLTree<DataType>` class, so a prefix is required.

The type `AVLTree<DataType>::AVLNodePointer` is called a "dependent name", because it is dependent on an instantiation of the class `AVLTree<DataType>`.

[Section 14.6](http://eelis.net/c++draft/temp.res) of the C++ standard requires use of the `typename` keyword every time a dependent name is used.

> A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is
>   dependent on a template-parameter is assumed not to name a type unless
>   the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified
>   by the keyword typename.

Comment: It works. Thank you. But I don't understand why we need to include typename?

Comment: See this article <http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html> for how the same syntax can mean two different things. `typename` is used to disambiguate them by saying what follows should be treated as a type.

Comment: You should add some explanations to your answer.